# ZXing.Net QR Code Size

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing, silverlight-5.0

I use this code for generating my qr code ZXing.Net (http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/)

```
IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter { Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE };
qrcode.Source = writer.Write(stringsecure.Text);
```

but the image is very very small..

How to set the dimension if possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the width and height of the resulting image with the Options property:

```
IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
   Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
   Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
      {
         Width = 400,
         Height = 400
      }
};
qrcode.Source = writer.Write(stringsecure.Text);
```

Comment: I really can't believe that. For me it works. Did you try some other values? Perhaps you should save the resulting image of the Write call to a file and check the width and height of it.

Comment: I tried it with the silverlight demo of zxing.net and it works for me the same way as the winforms demo for desktop. Perhaps you can provide a small sample project which I can try.

Comment: There seems to be a strange issue with the BarcodeWriter in C# when attempting to set a specific size. For instance, if I specify the options as `new QrCodeEncodingOptions { Width = 100, Height = 100, Margin = 0 }` , I get a barcode that appears to be a 100px square. But if I change both sizes to 90, the barcode appears to be about 50px square. Sizes seem to work at least semi-normally if using sizes like 200, 300, etc. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I tried it with the WinForms demo at it works like expected. Did you use another target platform like Windows Phone for your tests?

Answer (score 4):

Like John Dubya, I find that the sizing seems to "jump", it doesn't scale to any integer. I am using ZXing QRCodeWriter and BarcodeWriter, they both exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Each Matrix code type has symmetrical representation requirements. It will always jump to an even number that is a multiple of the codeword size.

Answer (score 1):

```
var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
barcodeWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
barcodeWriter.Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
 {
     Width = 400,
     Height = 400
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions();
        options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
        {
            DisableECI = true,
            CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
            Width = 200,
            Height = 200,
            PureBarcode = false,
            Margin = 0
        };
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this can answer to the question ?