# Pixelated text after printing C#

Tags: c#, printing

Everything is fine before printing the label, but after printing the label is pixelated. What could be the solution?

```
        private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
         Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
         /*
         float tgtWidthMM = 100; 
         float tgtHeightMM = 70;
         float tgtWidthInches = tgtWidthMM / 25.4f;
         float tgtHeightInches = tgtHeightMM / 25.4f;
         float srcWidthPx = bm.Width;
         float srcHeightPx = bm.Height; 
         float dpiX = srcWidthPx / tgtWidthInches;
         float dpiY = srcHeightPx / tgtHeightInches;

         bm.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);
         */
         pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
         e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bm, 0, 0);
         bm.Dispose();
        }
```

This picture mast be 100x70mm. I draw this picture here:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14))
        {
            BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };

            e.Graphics.DrawString("Miłego czytania!", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(118, 25));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(writer.Write(serialNumber), new Point(70, 65));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("text", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(70, 175));
        }

        using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 9))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("text", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(137, 205));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("text", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(140, 220));
        }
    }
```

[This is what the label looks like when printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgYTJ.png)

Comment: I agree, this looks terrible. (1) Have you verified that this is actually your code's fault? I.e., how does the label look if you print to it with Word? (2) Instead of drawing the contents in the PictureBox and then drawing the PictureBox on the printer, I'd try to draw the contents directly to the printer. Does the quality improve if you perform the steps from `pictureBox1_Paint` directly in `Doc_PrintPage`?

Comment: @Heinzi I did the code with pictureBox1_Paint in Doc_PrintPage and the text quality improved perfectly, only the barcode remained the same

Comment: Which barcode library do you use?

Comment: I use ZXing.Net

Comment: You should be able to set the target size in the encoding options (here's an example for QR-Code, but the same should be possible with `Code128EncodingOptions`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17527591/87698). I'd try to increase the (pixel) size to see if that improves the quality. Of course, if you're motivated, you can determine the DPI of your printer and try to calculate the optimal size.

Comment: Oh, and since `DrawImage` draws images according to their physical size (rather than their size in pixels), you might have to modify the DPI (`HorizontalResolution` and `VerticalResolution` properties) of the image returned by `writer.Write` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Printers typically have much higher resolution than screens, on the order of 600dpi compared to 96dpi  that is typical for screens. So if you create a bitmap suitable for the screen it will be pixelated when printed.

The best solution would be to draw your text and graphics directly to the printers graphic object instead of to the bitmap. Note that because of the different resolution you will likely need to recalculate positions & size of any text & graphics.

The other workaround would be to make the bitmap match the resolution of the printer, that might make it easier to ensure the printed label exactly matches the one on screen. For this to work you should probably invert the logic, i.e. draw your graphics to a bitmap, and then set the `picturebox.Image` property to this bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers. I found a solution there -> [Barcodes printing with irregular lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777389/barcodes-printing-with-irregular-lines)

Select the printer in Device and Printers > Printing Preferences > Graphics

Set Dithering to None